# Joining three tables in MySql using the sakila database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello I am trying to join three tables using the sakila database. It returns the column names i provided but no information. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
USE sakila;

SELECT c.name 'Category Name'
     , f.title 'Film Title'
     , f.description 'Film Description'
     , f.release_year 'Release Year'
  FROM sakila.category c
  JOIN sakila.film_category fc 
    ON c.category_id = fc.category_id 
  JOIN sakila.film f 
    ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
```

Comment: If you're naming the columns, you should be using the `AS` keyword. While optional, I'm pretty sure it's interpreting your column names incorrectly without the space.

Comment: @obsidianage why?

Comment: OP, your query is fine, and it's impossible to return columns with no rows. That's not how mysql works.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for the observed behavior is that there are no rows in the database that satisfy the conditions.

The query will return zero rows if any one of the three tables is empty i.e. contains zero rows. The query will also return zero rows if there are no rows that "match", for example, if the values of the `category_id` column in `film_category` is NULL or is a value that doesn't match a value in the `category_id` column of `category`.

---

First, check if any of the tables is empty:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM film ;
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM film_category ;
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM category ;
```

If all of the tables contain rows, next check if there are any rows that don't match. For example:

```
SELECT fc.category_id  
  FROM film_category fc
  LEFT
  JOIN category c
    ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
 WHERE fc.category_id IS NULL
```

Similarly for the `film_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

@spencer7593's answer is very good and serves as an example for investigating what might have gone wrong with a JOIN.

Specific to your case, I ran your query against the [Sakila DB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) and received plenty of results. Is it possible that in your copy of the DB one of the tables has been emptied for some reason or other?